# Redirect to dashboard if token exists using Angular AuthGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application with login page and dashboard. I have used `AuthGuard` to redirect the `route`to dashboard only if token exists and valid. But when I enter URL /login it goes back to login page even if the token exists.

This is my code which I have tried;

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

app routing module

```
  { path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: dashboard
  },
  { path: 'signin',
    component: signin
  }
```

authService: Here i'm setting my `isAuthenticated` to false and enabling it to true when i get the `access_token`

```
 private isAuthenticated = false;

 getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

 return this.http.post(api, data)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          if (response && response.access_token) {
            console.log(response.access_token);
            this.isAuthenticated = true;
            .......

           }
       })
```

Comment: might you share how does `getIsAuth` look like?

Comment: There isn't a route guard on the `signin` path, so a user will always be able to navigate to it.  You could develop a route guard which only allows for unauthenticated users, and have it redirect the user to the dashboard route if they're already logged in.

Comment: @satanTime updated my code. Please have a look

Comment: @Paul Let me try that way.

Comment: @SaiManoj, your question says `/login`, but your code has `/signin`.

Comment: Yep, then @Paul is right, if you want to have a redirect from `signin` to `/` - you need to implement it additionally.

Comment: @satanTime Thanks. It's working now with Paul idea. Can I delete this question?

Comment: better to ask him to post his comment as an answer and accept it :) ping @Paul

Comment: @Paul my bad I didn't notice. I'm working with someone application from middle. Just updated. Post your comment as answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a route guard on the signin path, so a user will always be able to navigate to it. You could develop a route guard which only allows for unauthenticated users, and have it redirect the user to the dashboard route if they're already logged in.